# How to make a Rest API Quickbooks API call for making charging on a credit card

Tags: php, api, rest, quickbooks

I wanto create API call function in php that get the Endpoint API of quickbooks and Pass the credit card info for payment that made by a client, What I'm not familiar with what is the request URL in the included image how can I turn to Normal PHP Curl with all these child header values.

The form is on WordPress website that the client insert his creadit card info
This's the RestApi that in Quickbooks doc

```
POST v4/payments/charges

Content type:application/json
Production Base URL:https://api.intuit.com
Sandbox Base URL:https://sandbox.api.intuit.com
```

link of the doc: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbpayments/docs/api/resources/all-entities/charges#create-a-charge

**So in summary : how to turn this Quickbooks Rest API with his child values to PHP curl or how genrally use Quickbooks API to make charge on a credit card?**

[image: qucikbooks]

Comment: And what's your question about this? Please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: how to turn this Quickbooks Rest API to PHP curl or how geenrally use  Quickbooks API  to make charge on a credit card?

Comment: Thanks, I also made an edit in summary